# WP7: How to Change Listbox Style Template programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

In WP7 I have a listbox with a pager defined in the listbox style template. What is the best way to access my pager control from code? I need to show/hide the ListPagerPanel based on number of records in datacontext.

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="StreamListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle1" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                <StackPanel x:Name="ListPagerPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
```

.... etc. Thanks

Comment: What is the class for the DataContext?

Comment: Hi Ritch, it is a Linq IQueryable<...> object.

Answer (score 4):

You can use similar piece of code for implementing style in dynamic way
         Style = Application.Current.Resources["StreamListBox"] as Style

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide code sample? This is my first WP7 app, just learning

Comment: you can simply set the style of you control by adding code like this, if your controls name is "ImageListBox". You can simply add the style like this ImageListBox.Style = Application.Current.Resources["StreamListBox"] as Style

Comment: so in order to implement this define your styles in ,<Phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resource> or in APP.xaml

Comment: but I want to dynamically change visibility of "ListPagerPanel". How can I do this?

Comment: you question is how to change listbox style template.. i replayed for that question.. What is this ListPagePannel? Your control or Style

Comment: Please see last line of the code in my post. Under ItemsPresenter there is a stackpanel, which I want to hide or show.